# Updating ADT ?( Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have updated my android SDK  and my ADT to 18 . But whenever i start eclipse it says "Your sdk version in 16 update it to 17 or above. What's the problem and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to do is that open 
'Help' >> 'Install New Software' >> check whether there is a URL entry for the ADT site for updation.

Check out complete solution at 
[How can I update my ADT in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse/17677199#17677199)