# How can I update my ADT in Eclipse?

Tags: android, adt

I have tried to update my Eclipse. Currently I have till 2.2 Android SDK in my Eclipse. Yesterday I have updated my Eclipse like this:

Eclipse -> window -> Android SDK Manager -> I have checked two check-boxes from list. Tools -> Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform Tools.

I have posted here some last lines of the message which I get from downloading and installing:

> Preparing to install archives
>   
>  Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 12
>   
>  Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 12
>   
>  Stopping ADB server succeeded.
>   
>  Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 12
>   
>  Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 20
>   
>  Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 20
>   
>  [post_tools_install.bat] Updating SDK Manager.exe
>   
>  [post_tools_install.bat]         1 file(s) copied.
>   
>  [post_tools_install.bat] Updating AVD Manager.exe
>   
>  [post_tools_install.bat]         1 file(s) copied.
>   
>  Installed Android SDK Tools, revision 20
>   
>  Stopping ADB server succeeded.
>   
>  Starting ADB server succeeded.
>   
>  Done. 2 packages installed.
>   
>  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
>   
>  Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason:                  dl-ssl.google.com
>   
>  Fetching URL: http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml
>   
>  Failed to fetch URL http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml, reason:       software.intel.com
>   
>  Done loading packages.

But after all this after I have closed Eclipse and again wanted to start, it throw the error:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 20.0.0 or above. Current version is 16.0.0.v201203301601-306762. Please update ADT to the latest version.

In preferences I received this error:

> This Android SDK requires Android Develop... Please update ADT to the latest version.

Comment: thats why it not fetched the details fully.. use high speed internet.. your on right path..

Comment: If https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ does not work for you, try using the http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/. The link without https worked for me. Make sure you launched eclipse as administrator

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You have updated the android sdk but not updated the adt to match with it.

You can update the adt from here

You might need to update the software source for your adt update

*Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.*

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try the same *Go to eclipse > help > Install new software * but now please do the follwing:

- Click on add
- Add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Give it any name.

It will list the updates available-  which should ideally be adt 20.xx

**Eclipse will restart** and hopefully everything should work fine for you.

Comment: Yes, you did. Only thing is, it requires additional help in programming so you also need update in adt plugin for eclipse

Comment: here in sdk manager i can see API 10,11,12,13,14,15, which i should install ? i have some low speed in internet....

Comment: If you want to support more devices, go with api level 10. If you want to develop with latest android features (android version 4), you should consider api level 14.

Comment: My suggestion is, initially, you download level 10 and gradually download all of them as android devices come in a variety and you might want to support as much as possible in your application

Comment: This happened with today's updates: 'Help -> Check for Check for Updates' found nothing, but the 'Help -> Install New Software' route worked.  Thanks.

Comment: "Android Native Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted."

Comment: That's assuming you can open the help screen.  On a fresh Eclipse install, with the SDK packaged, you won't be able to access that screen before selecting an SDK directory.  You won't be able to select an SDK directory unless you have the latest version.  So, the information is useless.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul I cannot my ADT plugin from 22.6 to 23.0 or to 23.0.2 getting dependency issue when trying to Click (after selecting the developer tools and selecting the Same path https:// as above)

Comment: Most likely, if you are upgrading ADT, you will first need to uninstall the old version of ADT.  This can be done by following this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt

Comment: Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ is not a valid repository location.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem. Since I already had the [ADT](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) address I could not follow the suggested fix. The reason why the update was not working in my case is that the ADT address was not checked in the list of "Available updates".

1) Go to eclipse > help > Install new software

2) Click on "Available Software site"

3) Check that you have the ADT address

4) If not add it following the  Murtuza Kabul's steps

5) if yes check that the address is checked (checkbox on the left of the address)

I run the update after having launched Eclipse as administrator to be sure that it was not going to have problems accessing the system folders

Answer (score 4):

I viewed the [Eclipse ADT documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and found out the way to get around this issue. I was able to Update My SDK Tool to 22.0.4 (Latest Version).

> **Solution is**: First Update ADT to 22.0.4 and then Update SDK Tool to
>   22.0.4

The above link says,

**ADT 22.0.4** is designed for use with **SDK Tools r22.0.4**. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r22.0.4 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so

What I had to do was update my ADT to 22.0.4 (Latest Version) and then I was able to update **SDK tool to 22.0.4**. I thought only SDK Tool has been updated not ADT, so I was updating the SDK Tool with Older ADT Version (22.0.1).

**How to Update your ADT to Latest Version**

1. In Eclipse go to `Help`
2. `Install New Software` ---> `Add`
3. inside Add Repository write the Name: `ADT` (or whatever you want)
4. Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
5. after loading you should get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
6. check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or check
7. Developer Tool only
8. click Next
9. Finish

Answer (score 1):

In my case opening 'Help' >> "Install New Software" had no entries for any URLs (previous url's were not there) - so I Manually added 'em.  And updated ... and Voilaaaa !!
Above posts have been very helpful in resolving this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Running as administrator then following other comments fixed the problem for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Reason to that is with the new update, they changed the URL for the Android Developer Tools update site to require HTTPS. If you are updating ADT, make sure you use HTTPS in the URL for the Android Developer Tools update site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where there's no files under Generated Java files, BuildConfig and R.java were missing. The automatic build option is not generating.
In Eclipse under Project, uncheck Build Automatically. Then under Project select Build Project. You may need to fix the projec