# Error after Android Development tools 23

Tags: android

I have updated Android Development tools to version 23. But when I restart eclipse, i get error like this ...

[image]

how to fix it ? sorry for my english ..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse

Comment: yes, I've done it many times but always getting error :
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

As the message clearly says you need to update your ADT.
`Please update ADT to the latest version`
You can get the latest ADT Plugin from the [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) given in the Google Developers Website.

Comment: yes, I've done it many times but always getting error :
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.