# I don't know what exactly is wrong with my SDK and ADT Plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I was about to work on swipe tabs and upon creating a new android application project, I set the minimum required SDK in Honeycomb (3.0), my target SDK in Kitkat (4.4) and to compile it with Jellybean (4.3). Now, the first problem I encountered was I wasn't able to create a new project. I clicked the finish button but nothing happens.

As soon as I was able to create a file, I haven't typed a code but there were already several errors saying that "R cannot be resolved to a variable" I figured out it was because of the compatibility measurements so I quickly updated my SDK. Every single possible update, I updated it. I have also read that I need to update my ADT Plugins as well so I did what Murtuza Kabul said here [How to update ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse). I ran my Eclipse as admin and this is the error message I got

> Error when loading the SDK
>
> Error: Error parsing
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point. Error:
>   Error parsing
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Would somebody please give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2):

There´s a kind of problem with `android wear` packages for `API 22`, so my solution was deleting this two packages from the `API 22`

[image]

Now the problem is solved =)

> Error: Error Parsing
>   C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:Skin'. No child
>   element is expected at this point.

Comment: the error message finally disappeared. Thanks a lot for that. Now I have this message in my logcat that says "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies" Do you have an Idea how to fix that?

Comment: probably you have the problem with android-support-v4.jar, remember you must have only one support library reference in your proyect if you have the reference in your project you can delete the .jar located inside folder /libs