# Show card view in graphical layout

Tags: android, android-layout, adt, android-cardview

I'm using CardView in my layout. I want see my layout in graphical layout tab so i set android version for rendering layout to 22 but in graphical layout show this message: 
"This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in"

When i have a view without `cardView`, and set api version to below 21, i can to see the graphical layout.

I download ADT-23.0.3 and in `install new software` --> `archive` , set this ADT, but again i have above error message.
How can i fix this? I should to see graphical layout in some devices but now i can't.

Please if you have any guide, say to me . Thanks for advises :)

Answer (score 0):

try using  android.support.v7.widget.CardView

here is a example 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-CardView/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_card_view.xml

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using cardview jar file from appcompatibility. My application have not any error, when i run my application on my device, run perfect and i can see cardView. my problem is showing layout in graphical layout. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse . I can view card view in layout in android studio, but it has API22.