# How to solve the issue with "your app will not work unless you update your google play service"?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am having Google+ login in my app.I have done all the steps which was mentioned in this link [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)
The issue is when I run my app it shows "this app will not work unless you update your Google play service".Then I updated my google-play services to its latest version.
later I update the Google-API Intel x86 atom_64 system image under API-21.Still I find the same message to appear.
can't fix this issue need help.Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Current googleplay service version is com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'. To use that add this to build.gradle dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: Thanks..but can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I am using eclipse,how can i do it here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the feature that you use really needs the latest version of google apis, you can use older versions of the google play services by adding

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

under dependencies in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting app preferences. **Settings>Apps>menu>reset app preferences**. This sometimes helps with Play issues.

Comment: Might be , there is a s/w update , which you are unaware of.. n is causing this prob.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import google play service from sdk->extras->google->googleplayservices->googleplayservice-lib;
Then rightclick on project -> properties ->add 
add the library

to get new version go to sdkmanager->extras->googleplayservice (install or update)

if it is not available then you have to update adt tools and then it will appear.

for that use link

[How can I update my ADT in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse)