# Error in all android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have been using eclips for android programming since about 6 months. Everything was working smooth till yesterday.

On restarting Eclipse it shows error on every project and all of them say:

> Unable to resolve target 'android-21'.

And I can't even create any new project as it always says

> Base Theme "Holo Light with Dark Action Bar" requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8

And I cant start SDK manager from eclipse. Please help, and thank you everyone in advance. :)

Comment: update you eclipse ADT version ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634568/how-can-i-update-my-adt-in-eclipse

Comment: already tried it out, but didn't help. Thank you for the response though

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows -> Android SDK Manager Install the Android API Level you want, in this case 21.

Once you've finished installing, go to Window -> Preference -> Android. You should get a list of available targets. Click Apply then Ok.

Now right click your project, go to properties. Click Android. Choose your desired target.

Comment: I cant load SDK manager either, I alreay messed a lot to try to fix it. Tried editing android.bat and copied all .dll files to tools. I got diffrent erros on every step. Now it's giving an error as follow:
 [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM